Is it possible to block the Staging Ground badges popover?
For the last several weeks, I've been regularly seeing this popover tip on Stack Overflow questions, which usually covers part of the question. There is nothing at all useful for me about staging or badges. Even if there were, it would be enough to see it once (a simple flag in the user account or a cookie would be sufficient to implement "show-once" behavior).
Since this "feature" is not becoming more polite, is there some way to block it from interfering with ordinary site usage?


As a workaround, try using your adblocker and blocking it

Where is that shown? Like which page/view? It doesn't show for me and I suspect it's because I have the left menu hidden via my user settings. If I expand the menu still nothing shows up.

So clicking on the "X" button didn't remove it/it popped up again despite doing that? Did you maybe clear your browser data?

Per the consensus in this Q&A, I'm migrating this to Meta Stack Overflow. The SG is only available on SO atm and there are no plans stated to make it available on more sites on the network.

It's popping up from the "Staging Ground" item in the left sidebar. When I clear it with the "x" button, it does go away for a while. But it keeps coming back later! It would really be nice for it to stop 100% after showing only one time. No browser data has been cleared in the last year or so.

Oh, great, I'm not getting the popup. And if I can't dismiss it, it also means I can't dismiss the highlighting of SG in the left menu.

@ByronHawkins Maybe you configured your browser to clear some stuff (cookies or whatever) automatically? When I dismissed it, I never got it again.

According to a staff member here this popup should go away by clicking the close button or opening the link inside the popup. Can you try opening the "See new badges" link, does that work?

It probably won't appear again today, but I won't be surprised to see it again tomorrow. There is no automatic clearing of browser data. What would be ideal is to have an account setting that simply says "no popups", meaning not even once.

It would be a bad idea if this was implemented as a persisting the "this was dismissed" in the browser. It would mean that you get the popup with each new browser and each new device. Given that SE do store such things (one-time popups) against the user profile, I would be quite surprised if this was saved in the browser. Therefore, that suggest there is a problem on the SE side. Perhaps only for some user accounts.

Sorry about that Byron. So the SG badges popover should be displayed until a user clicks the × dismiss icon.  At that point, a flag is stored to user preferences in the DB and should never be shown again, regardless of browser / session / etc.  Anything else is a bug.  Now there are 2 popovers we've launched since the beginning of SG: 1 calling attention to SG itself for someone who qualifies as a reviewer, and 1 calling attention to the new badges.  What admittedly can be a little unititive is that clicking on the SG nav menu link doesn't actually dismiss it.  You have to explicitly click.

In the last 2 months I've dismissed this kind of popup more than 20 times (probably many more than that), though admittedly I rarely read what it says so I can't say whether the content has ever changed. There are 2 browsers I use for SO, both Firefox on Fedora, both always logged in. Let me know if there's any other info that would be useful.

I've confirmed that those flags should be set correctly for you (Byron), and so you shouldn't see the SG popover anymore in any browser.  But traiging this to our team to double check and see if there are any edge cases we're missing or ways to improve the UX.

@KyleMit Thanks, it does seem to work. Haven't seen the popup in a week now.

We've updated the popover to be dismissed upon clicking the SG nav menu link. This provides an additional method of dismissing the popover, along with clicking the 'X' or opening the link inside the popover. As Kyle mentioned in his comment, a user preference flag is stored in the database when this happens, ensuring the popover will not be shown again.
